# Copying rows and changing values MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

With below code I tend to copy rows where `Country = Morocco` and `Model = S-Class`. From this copied rows I need to change the value `Fuel to Petrol` and `Status to Average`.

The weird thing is, when I pass this query in the workbench it seems to work, but when I want to get it done in Python I get the following error: `OperationalError: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: Connection not available`. Where lies the problem?

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host= 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        passwd = '*****.',
        database= 'my_db'
    )
cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered = True)

q4 = ("INSERT INTO my_cars(Car, Model, Country, System, Fuel, Status) (SELECT Car, Model, Country, System,'Petrol', 'Average' FROM my_cars WHERE Model = 'S-class' AND Country= 'Morocco')")

mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
                            
cursor.execute(q4)
```

Comment: It seems like you close the database connection before executing the query. Can you try to move the last line above of mydb.close() ?

Comment: @Baris that was it yes! thank you, I figured it out after I just revisedmy code lol

Comment: Note that as of mysql 8, system is a reserved word. And those parentheses around the SELECT aren't doing anything

Comment: @Strawberry True I added `` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You executed the query (`cursor.execute(q4)`) after you closed the DB connection. `mydb.close()`. You cannot use the DB connection anymore after you closed the connection unless you reconnect it.

Comment: lol, thats true! Seems to work now. Thank you. 1 more question I want to add another `AND`  after `WHERE` can I just do 2x `AND`?

Comment: Yes. For example, `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a=1 AND b=2 AND c=3 AND d=4`